# Preserve Symlinks in Angular Libraries

Tags: angular, npm, angular8, npm-link, angular-cli-v8

I have a problem.

I'm trying to make a Angular 8 Library using ng-cli, but i can't preserve symlinks from my external application using `npm link`.

I've tried to add this on my angular.json:

```
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build",
      "options": {
        "preserveSymlinks": true,
        "tsConfig": "projects/button/tsconfig.lib.json",
        "project": "projects/button/ng-package.json"
      }
    },
```

but got:

```
"Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path ""
should NOT have additional properties(preserveSymlinks)."
```

I found that it doesn't work for libraries.

Then I tried to add this to my tsconfig.lib.json:

```
 "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "annotateForClosureCompiler": true,
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "enableResourceInlining": true,
    "preserveSymlinks": true
  }
```

And nothing happend.

I searched here for a solution, but couldn't find anything like it.

How can I make it?

Thank you!

Comment: Does it make a difference if you add `"preserveSymlinks": true` to the *tsconfig.json* file for the application *consuming* the library?

Comment: @R.Richards I saw this in this issue on git: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31989#issuecomment-523375803

Comment: I Need this, because when I use my component (inside the library) on my external application I got this error:

`NgBradButtonComponent.html:2 ERROR NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgClassImpl -> ElementRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NgClassImpl -> ElementRef]: `

Cause my component has _ngClass_ and _ngIf_.

I don't know if it is the right way.

Comment: I can see why you need it, it makes sense. I was hoping that adding that in the consuming app would work. Hopefully someone will post an answer.

Comment: @andersonbalves did you find any solution for this? I am facing this same issue.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I believe you need to add the preserveSymlinks option in the angular.json located at the project that will consume your library. For instance, I was testing locally, and I added it in my architect -> build -> options.

You will able to find more info here: https://dev.to/nieds/getting-started-building-component-libraries-with-angular-cli-4ncj

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

In angular 13... this allowed me to use symlinks with `ng serve`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Adding this to my `tsconfig.lib.json` worked for me:

```
 "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "preserveSymlinks": true
  }
```

Are you sure you are not overriding this property in `tsconfig.lib.prod.json` and making a production build?

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked to add the following code section to the ng-packagr library's tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": [ "./node_modules/@angular/*" ]
    }
  }
}
```

Setup: Angular 14, ng-packagr 14.2.2

Comment: Can you explain this further? I haven't seen this before.