Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor
good evening, I am updating a library with the version of Angular 17, before I used Angular 13 and it worked correctly. However, when testing it in a project with Angular 17, it does not let me call my components or my modules. Has anyone dealt with this error? Leave package.json from the library, from the project and capture the error.
package.json from both projects
main.ts:11 ERROR Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `runInInjectionContext`. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203
at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:1093:15)
at ɵɵinject (core.mjs:1106:60)
at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.mjs:11047:16)
at NodeInjectorFactory.DimoComponent_Factory [as factory] (dimo.component.ts:13:27)
at getNodeInjectable (core.mjs:5984:44)
at instantiateAllDirectives (core.mjs:11907:27)
at createDirectivesInstances (core.mjs:11306:5)
at ɵɵelementStart (core.mjs:23045:9)
at HomeComponent_Template (template.html:5:5)
at executeTemplate (core.mjs:11268:9)

I tried some workarounds similar to my case, but they didn't work for me. I'm not sure if it's the @angular dependencies or some extra configuration that needs to be done for the angular libraries, has anyone dealt with this?
@Component({
 selector: 'lib-dimo',
 templateUrl: './dimo.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./dimo.component.scss']
})
export class DimoComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() styleClass = 'mobile';
 @Input() descriptionCode = '';
 @Output() parentObservable: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
 @Output() executionDimo: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
 localFormGroup: UntypedFormGroup;
 dimoCaption: ICaption = {};
 dimoShowStatus: IShowStatus = { status: false };

 dimoAutorization: any[] = [
   { label: 'SI', value: true },
   { label: 'NO', value: false }
 ];

 constructor(private _dimoLibraryService: DimoLibraryService) {
   this.localFormGroup = new UntypedFormGroup({
     value: new UntypedFormControl(true)
   });
 }

 public ngOnInit(): void {
   this.emitExecuteEnrollment();
   this._dimoLibraryService
     .getDimoShowStatus()
     .pipe(
       tap(showStatus => {
         if (showStatus.status == true) {
           this.emitExecutionNull(true);
           this._dimoLibraryService
             .getDimoCaption(this.descriptionCode)
             .subscribe(dimoCaption => (this.dimoCaption = dimoCaption));
         } else {
           this.emitExecutionNull(false);
         }
       })
     )
     .subscribe(showStatus => (this.dimoShowStatus = showStatus));
 }

 emitExecuteEnrollment(): void {
   this.parentObservable.emit(
     this._dimoLibraryService.setDimoEnrollment(
       this.localFormGroup.get('value')?.value
     )
   );
 }

 emitExecutionNull(emitEvent: boolean): void {
   this.executionDimo.emit(emitEvent);
 }
}

Solved:
I already solved my doubt, adding a "preserveSymlinks": true attribute in the angular.json file. Very similar to what they suggest in the following references:

Preserve Symlinks in Angular Libraries
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35586#issuecomment-750696076


please share the contents of dimo.component.ts:

@NarenMurali I've edited my post, thx

I already solved my doubt, adding a "preserveSymlinks": true attribute in the angular.json file. Very similar to what they suggest in the following references:


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58260202/preserve-symlinks-in-angular-libraries
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35586#issuecomment-750696076


